Canopy cover metrices
I am trying to get canopy height metrices such as the area of a land that is covered by the trees with height up to 5 meters, with height up to 10 meters and so on, using the GEDI canopy cover data. Is there anyone who has done this already? If you have, can you guide me?

Please edit your question to specify which GEDI level/product and what sotware you use.
